# render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[Error occurs while calling render function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Z1S.png)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please post the *full traceback* and the relevant view as *code*, not as images of code.

Comment: thiis error occurs while using render function of Json Renderer

Comment: from .serializers import StudentSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def student_detail(request):
    stu=Student.objects.get(id=2)
    s=StudentSerializer(stu)
    print(s.data)
    json_data=JSONRenderer.render(s.data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data,content_type='application/json')

Comment: please *edit* the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you aim on returning a JSON response try using a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) object as stated in the official docs

Example code:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers

def student_detail(request):
   obj = Student.objects.get(id=2)
   json_data = serializers.serialize('json', [obj, ]) # serialize method needs an iterator
   return JsonResponse(json_data, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to create your render; `render = JSONRenderer()` and then use method with passing argument data `render.render(data=data)` where data is `NameOfYourSerializer.data`